# Dynamically generate SVG with images inside?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

AngularJS app.

Basically I've to make an horizontal arrow-like drawing with images that will be repeating inside depending on the array of items i sent to the html(ng-repeat).

I got told the best would be svg so here I am, but my knowledge of svg is pretty low. So I managed to make a little arrow with fixed witdh and height. But now I need it a lot bigger.

So I read about viewBox online. It scales the  items I have in the SVG, but I have two problems so far.

- Images don't work.
- All  items are stacked up and don't follow the space in between them that I had before.

This code is the working code I have right now, so you get an idea of the element I'm trying to draw. I use the  element so I can ng-repeat it with tooltips and text inside, this code is simplified.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.justaclass {
    fill: #9b3d9c;
    background-color: #9b3d9c;
}

.justaclass-group {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}


.justaclass-image {
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg width="8" height="34">
      <path class="justaclass"
            d="M 0 0 L 7 17 L 0 34 L 17 34 L 17 0 z">
      </path>
  </svg>
  <svg width="33" height="34" class="justaclass justaclass-image">
  
      <image x="0" y="3" width="33" height="25" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg"></image>
      
  </svg>
  <div class="justaclass-group">
  
      <svg width="50" height="34" class="justaclass image">
           
          <image width="45" height="30"
                 x="0" y="0"
                 href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg">
          </image>
          
      </svg>

  <svg width="10" height="34">
      <path class="justaclass"
            d="M 0 0 L 0 34 L 10 17 z">
      </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

The code isn't perfect pixel-wise here, but that's not my main issue.

Now that I try to make it bigger with viewBox, **I can draw the 4 elements** but they are misplaced. So If I add *display:flex* or *display:table* I quite cannot get the elements aligned horizontally, the  elements just disappear.

Anyone got any idea of how to dinamically resize all this elements plus making them all in the same line just like display flex would do?

**My first try at doing the above image with viewBox**
But If I add display:flex into the container, the svg's are gone and I only see images.

```css
.container {}

.justaclass {
    fill: #9b3d9c;
    background-color: #9b3d9c;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <svg viewBox="0 0 150 50">
        <path class="justaclass"
              d="M 0 0 L 7 17 L 0 34 L 17 34 L 17 0 z">
        </path>
    </svg>

    <svg viewBox="0 0 150 50">
        <image width="150" height="50" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg"></image>
    </svg>

    <svg viewBox="0 0 150 50">
        <image width="150" height="50" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg"></image>
    </svg>

    <svg viewBox="0 0 150 50">
        <path class="justaclass"
              d="M 0 0 L 0 34 L 10 17 z">
        </path>
    </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: THe image(s) you link are not really SVG files, but wiki pages. Try the raw SVG file url: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg. For your alignment problem, could you try to describe more precisely what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks. I added a second snippet that shows what I want to do. Basically is removing the fixed sizes of the first one, to make a new arrow with the same elements, but scalable.

Comment: Please check the syntax of you CSS in the second example. You cannot use SCSS here. And add width and height to the <image> elements, SVG knows no auto sizes.

Comment: Done, I added viewBox to the container too. But still the same, I have the four elements, but I cannot put them next to one another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of things that need to change here. First lets talk about `viewBox`. This attribute describes how the numbers *inside* the `<svg>` tag relate to those *outside*. It gives a rectangle into which the inside content is rendered. Then, this rectangle is scaled such that it fits into the size given by `width` and `height`. That means, giving a `viewBox` without also defining `width` and `height` makes not much sense, as the size the content should be *scaled to* is missing.

What happens if the aspect ratio of the viewBox and that of the width and height do not match? As a default, the content is set into the middle and scaled such that it just fits. Other values can be given with the [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attribute. For example, to get the left "arrow" part to the right of its rectangle (so there is no gap), set `preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid meet"`.

`width` and `height` can be given as attributes for SVG content or as CSS properties. It makes sense to define them as styles if they are to be changeable.

Your linked images do not need to have a concrete size. Giving them `width="100%" height="100%"` scales them to the containing SVG element, without distorting them (unless you define so with `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.container svg {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.container .justaclass {
    fill: #9b3d9c;
    background-color: #9b3d9c;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 8 34" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid meet">
        <path
              d="M 0 0 L 7 17 L 0 34 L 17 34 L 17 0 z">
        </path>
    </svg>

    <svg class="justaclass">
        <image width="100%" height="100%" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg"></image>
    </svg>

    <svg class="justaclass">
        <image width="100%" height="100%" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg"></image>
    </svg>

    <svg viewBox="0 0 10 34" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet">
        <path
              d="M 0 0 L 0 34 L 10 17 z">
        </path>
    </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: This solves it, but then I cannot scale it to a parent's div size, for example. I've been trying to put those css svg width and height up, but only the height scales the actual item, and the width just leaves a huge empty blank space left and right of the arrow, is that just, not doable?

Comment: You've seen that in my example I have set separate widths for `<svg>` with and without the `.justaclass`? In general, think about the image in the `<svg>` as one rectangle fitting inside another. If the aspect ratio of the inner rectangle does not match that of the outer one, it will not fill its longer direction.

Answer (score 1):

viewBox defines the size of the contents of the svg *before* being scaled. You need to set them to the original size of your image and then scale the elements up either with the width and height tags you used before or with css. Here's a fiddle of everything scaled up to double size: https://jsfiddle.net/ohnqbufa/

You can see here that the viewport of your first element is set to the original size and the width and height are set to double.

```
<svg width="16" height="68" viewBox="0 0 8 34">
    <path class="justaclass"
          d="M 0 0 L 7 17 L 0 34 L 17 34 L 17 0 z">
    </path>
</svg>
```